# Parse SOAP Response using Simple XML PHP

Tags: php

After passing SOAP response using simplexml i got the following out put. How can i get the value of attributes of domain ie, name and avail.

code used:

```
 $xmlString = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result);    
       $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
       print_r($xml);



SimpleXMLElement Object([soapBody] => SimpleXMLElement Object ([CheckAvailabilityResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object([CheckAvailabilityResult] => &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?&gt;
&lt;check&gt;
    &lt;domain name="MYNAMEISNIJIL.COM" avail="1" canBackorder="0"/&gt;
&lt;/check&gt;) ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you have escaped XML in the return (which is a bad practice I'll ignore for now..). Also, look into the `children()` function to work with namespaces instead of your `preg_replace`.... Ignoring that, this would work for you:

```
  $outerxml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
  $innerxml = simplexml_load_string( htmlspecialchars_decode(
     $outerxml->soapBody->CheckAvailabilityResponse->CheckAvailabilityResult));
```

On a side note, I usually use this tidbit to leverage `SOAPClient` to parse soap responses:

```
//the soap way
class SneakyFauxSoap extends SoapClient {
    public $response;
    function __doRequest($val){
        return $this->response;
    }
}

$soap = new SneakyFauxSoap(null,
    array(
        'uri' =>'something',
        'location'=>'something',
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
$soap->response = $x;
var_dump($soap->somerandomfunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Wrikken's answer, I wrote a simple to use class that works
with PHP 5.3:

```
class SoapParser extends SoapClient {
  private $xml;

  function __construct($options) {
    $options['location'] = $options['uri'] = 'dummy';
    parent::__construct(null, $options);
  }

  public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version,
                              $one_way = 0)
  {
    return $this->xml;
  }

  public function parse($xml) {
    $this->xml = $xml;
    return $this->dummyFunction();
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$soapParser = new SoapParser(array('soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1'));
try {
  var_dump($soapParser->parse($response));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```