# How to generate SOAP request XML?

Tags: php, soap, domdocument, soapui, soap-client

As a SOAP newbie, I am trying to build a client to a SOAP service in PHP.
The catch: The [PHP SOAP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) can *not* be used to directly
interface with the service, because HTTP downloads are happening outside
of the app - see below.

Now, there are *two requests* that need to be executed in order:

1. **SignIn**: I manually created the **SignIn** request's XML using the
   [PHP DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Also I found a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502098/parse-soap-response-using-simple-xml-php/14789752#14789752) to deserialize the
   response into a hierarchy of XML objects, *exactly* as it would be
   returned by the PHP SOAP extension. So far, so good.
2. **Search**: According to the definition that I can parse in
   [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), this request is scary big:

   - Some search parameters have to be specified twice, for unclear
     reason.
   - Large XML chunks from the response of **SignIn** have to be
     passed on. One such chunk is a *SecurityToken* which is not a
     string but a complex hierarchy of XML elements.

How do I best build the **Search** request? Should I just use the PHP
DOM extension as for **SignIn**, or are there smarter ways?

*PS:* Explanation how HTTP downloads are realized: The PHP app writes a HTTP
request to a database. A *download daemon* then picks up the request,
executes it, and writes the response to the database. Finally, another instance
of the PHP app gets it from there. This is a realization of asynchronous
requests.

Comment: Build it with dom or [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: @mkaatman Well, if there is no smarter way, then this would be the answer. In fact, I probably don't even want use the [trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502098/parse-soap-response-using-simple-xml-php/14789752#14789752) and instead do it all with DOM. That way I should be able to easily pass on the chunks from the **SignIn** response to the **Search** request.

Comment: Please double-check PHP's SOAPClient documentation, I think you can inject your own handler for HTTP via the context settings or even stream-wrappers directly - not not even you can interfere earlier with `SoapClient` itself. So better double-check, what you write in your first paragraph must not be the show stopper.